# check whether $5$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As one can show that the integer $5$ is reducible in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, as $5=(2-i)(2+i)$, how can I check whether $5$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$?

Comment: If you can't remember the slick ways to do these kinds of problems, you can always try solving $5 = (a+b\sqrt{-2})(c+d\sqrt{-2})$ and use some elementary properties of real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{{\bf{Z}}[X]}{\left<5,X^{2}+2\right>}\cong\dfrac{{\bf{Z}}_{5}[X]}{\left<X^{2}+2\right>}
\end{align*}
and $X^{2}+2$ has no root in ${\bf{Z}}_{5}[X]$.